# Solve the equation $x^2 + y^2=z^2$ using group cohomology.

Tags: homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

Now  a  few  weeks   ago  I  saw on  the  Internet a  proof of  the  equation $x^2 + y^2=z^2$.  Now  I  search  the  link  but  I  didn't  find  it.  Can   you  help me?  Maybe  you  know.Thank  you!

Comment: Do you mean in integers? It's very unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for this sort of proof? http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10879/intuition-for-group-cohomology/10903#10903

Comment: This  is  the  link!  Thank  you!